# Get caret position in RichTextBox_Click event

Tags: c#, winforms, click, richtextbox

I'm working on a text editor which includes a `RichTextBox`. One of the features that I want to implement is to show in a `TextBox` the current Line and Column of the caret of the forementioned `RichTextBox` at any moment.

Here's part of the code that I use (the rest of my code has nothing to do with my issue):

```
int selectionStart = richTextBox.SelectionStart;
int lineFromCharIndex = richTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart);
int charIndexFromLine = richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineFromCharIndex);

currentLine = richTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart) + 1;
currentCol = richTextBox.SelectionStart - charIndexFromLine + 1;
```

At this point, I should mention that when someone is using a `RichTextBox`, there are three ways that the caret can change location:

- By changing the `Text` of the `RichTextBox`
- By using the arrow keys on the keyboard
- By clicking anywhere on the `RichTextBox`

The code that I posted above works with no issues in the first two cases. However, it doesn't really work in the third case.

I tried using the `Click` event and I noticed that the `selectionStart` variable would always get the value of 0, which means that I always get the same and wrong results. Moreover, using the same code on other events like `MouseClick` and `MouseUp` did not solve my problem since `selectionStart` is 0 even in the duration of these events.

So, how can I get the current Line and column everytime the user clicks on the `RichTextBox`?

Comment: Use the RichTextBox.SelectionChanged event.  And use a Label to display the position.  Lots of RTB editor projects at codeproject.com

Comment: Using `RichTextBox_SelectionChanged` seems to do the trick. `SelectionStart` gets the correct value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        RichTextBox box = (RichTextBox)sender;
        Point mouseLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        box.SelectionStart = box.GetCharIndexFromPosition(mouseLocation);
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
        int selectionStart = richTextBox.SelectionStart;
        int lineFromCharIndex = box.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart);
        int charIndexFromLine = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineFromCharIndex);

        currentLine = box.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart) + 1;
        currentCol = box.SelectionStart - charIndexFromLine + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm getitng an error: `'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: It needs to be `MouseEventArgs`, not `EventArgs`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error, but I can't really see how this can help. Sure, I get the location of the mouse icon, and then by doing a few changes to the X and Y values I can get the Line and Column, but after doing some tests, I noticed that it doesn't always help. What I used is: `e.X - rtb.Location.X / [the height of a character in pixels]` and `e.Y - rtb.Location.Y / [the width of a character in pixels]`. It works, but only when both scrollbars are at the very top/left position. Making any changes to fix would be (I think) a bit too complex to do.

Comment: You don't have to change the e.X and e.Y. e.X and e.Y come from MouseEventArgs, so you must use this event. It literally tells you the exact character index within the RichTextBox the mouse hit. Does that make sense? I finished my code example to dovetail it into your other code. See how it works now?

Comment: Also, you must use the `MouseUp` event of the `RichTextBox`, not the Form. If you don't, as you say, it's impossible. Somewhere in your code or code-behind ensure there's a `RichTextBox.MouseUp += richTextBox1_MouseUp`. Otherwise, you aren't catching this event.

Comment: My mistake. You were right. It actually works. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you really want is to handle the [`TextBoxBase.SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionchanged(v=vs.100).aspx) event. Then *any* action that causes the selection to change will invoke your code, and as an added benefit the current selection will have been updated by the time your event handler is called, and you'll be assured of getting correct values.

If that does not address your specific need, then I must not be understanding the question. In that case, please provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to do, with a precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.